# Apache Flink throws exception when submitting a job through Jenkins and Spinnaker

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We are using Apache Flink 1.16.1 configured as a standalone Kubernetes pod ,for one of our application to read from confluent Kafka topics to do event correlation. We are using the flink's Table API join for the same (in SQL format).We are able to submit the job using the flink's UI. For our DEV environment , we implemented a jenkins pipeline, which downloads the jar that is required to submit the job and also creates the flink kubernetes pods and copy the downloaded jar to the flink pod's folder and uses the flink's run command to submit the job.The deployment step happens through the spinnaker webhook. We use a docker file to create the kubernetes pods, also have a docker-entrypoin.sh which has the flink run command to submit the job.

Everything works fine, but when the job is getting submitted , we get the below exception.

The flink run command used is

```
flink run  /opt/flink/lib/application-0.0.1.jar
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:867)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:827)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:918)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730)
        at com.sample.SampleStreamingApp.main(SampleStreamingApp.java:157)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'insert-into_default_catalog.default_database.Sample'.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2203)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:206)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultExecutor.java:95)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:850)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
15:06:44.964 [main] ERROR org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend - Error while running the command.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:98) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:843) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:240) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1087) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1165) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) [application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1165) [application-0.0.1.jar:?]
aused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:867) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:827) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:918) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.sample.SampleStreamingApp.main(SampleStreamingApp.java:157) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'insert-into_default_catalog.default_database.Sample'.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2203) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:206) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.DefaultExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultExecutor.java:95) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:850) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:827) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:918) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:730) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.sample.SampleStreamingApp.main(SampleStreamingApp.java:157) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:448) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:271) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489) ~[application-0.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:448)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:271)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1125)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.DirectExecutorService.execute(DirectExecutorService.java:217)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$orTimeout$12(FutureUtils.java:489)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        ... 9 more
```